# Make [mro] a synonym of method-resolution-order

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

[mro](/questions/tagged/mro) is an acronym for [method-resolution-order](/questions/tagged/method-resolution-order), I suggest that they become synonyms. Even though [mro](/questions/tagged/mro) is more commonly used than [method-resolution-order](/questions/tagged/method-resolution-order), I suggest that [method-resolution-order](/questions/tagged/method-resolution-order) be the master tag as the name is clearer.

Comment: I agree, but 32 posts can easily be manually retagged.

Comment: In fact, retagging is going to be required as the system won't let you add a synonym using a tag with a lot more questions attached to it.

Comment: I've now retagged enough that the balance has been shifted enough; tomorrow I should be able to suggest the synonym (as I now have enough upvotes in the `method-resolution-order` tag).

Comment: Ah ok, I knew about the preference for the most used being the master, but didn't know this was enforced by the system. Thanks for the manual re-tagging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I retagged all but two posts yesterday, so that I could add the synonym today.

I did this deliberately because `method-resolution-order` doesn't jump out as quickly as `mro` does, the synonym would help people redirect to the better explicit tag name.

Then this morning someone had [helpfully changed both remaining tags](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4584900)..

I recreated the tag and [suggested the synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/method-resolution-order/synonyms). Feel free to vote it up!

Comment: Hehe, I thought I was being helpful indeed. :) Sorry.